# Unable to read HDFS using Java program: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to `cat` a file stored in the HDFS. I tried the methods provided under both the headings, [Reading Data from a Hadoop URL](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=Nff49D7vnJcC&pg=PA51&dq=Displaying+files+from+a+Hadoop+filesystem+on+standard+output+using+a+URLStreamHandler+definitive+guide&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YP4JUazVBs7V0gGnrYG4BQ&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Displaying%20files%20from%20a%20Hadoop%20filesystem%20on%20standard%20output%20using%20a%20URLStreamHandler%20definitive%20guide&f=false) and [Reading Data Using the FileSystem API](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=Nff49D7vnJcC&pg=PA53&dq=Displaying+files+from+a+Hadoop+filesystem+on+standard+output+by+using+the+FileSystem+directly+definitive+guide&hl=en&sa=X&ei=n_4JUYW_JbKQ0QHWhoGIBw&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Displaying%20files%20from%20a%20Hadoop%20filesystem%20on%20standard%20output%20by%20using%20the%20FileSystem%20directly%20definitive%20guide&f=false) of the book **Hadoop: The Definitive Guide** but I keep getting the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class <class_name>
```

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide the command you are executing to run the java program and java source

Comment: I have provided them. Check the links to the book in the question. The code and command is present there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see all the pages in the link, but I think I know what's going on. You are trying to run the commands like this.

```
% hadoop URLCat <HDFS URL>
```

The error you are getting is related to Hadoop being not able to find the class `URLCat` in its classpath. You can either edit the `hadoop` command file to include `URLCat` in its classpath. This is not advised though.

What is best is to create a jar file with the `URLCat` class inside and call that with the following command

```
% hadoop jar <Path to Jar>/<Your Jar>.jar URLCat <HDFS URL>
```

Read this blog [post](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2012/11/storing-hadoop-wordcount-example-with.html) for more information which shows how to run a jar.

Comment: Alright, now though I am not getting the previous error, I am getting the following new error: `INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried n time(s).`
And you should be able to see the entire book. I am able to!

Comment: No I can't see the whole book. have you started the hdfs? $HADOOP_HOME/bin/start-all.sh

Comment: I can run other jobs, so I believe the cluster is running alright. And it's a free book. Why don't you download it from [here](http://bigdata.googlecode.com/files/Oreilly.Hadoop.The.Definitive.Guide.3rd.Edition.Jan.2012.pdf) and look at pages 58 and 60 for the code.

Comment: What do you pass in as the <HDFS URL>?

Comment: `hdfs://localhost/<rest_of_the_path>`

Comment: I replaced `localhost` with the name of the name node and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

step 1: Compile Java Program:

```
javac URLCat.java -classpath $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.0.jar
```

step 2: Create jar file :

```
jar cvf URLCat.jar URLCat.class
```

Step 3: Execute program : (mention your hdfs file location)

```
hadoop jar URLCat.jar URLCat hdfs://localhost:9000/pcode/wcinput.txt
```